# Is that possible to communicate between two iWatch

Tags: ios, iphone, watchkit

Am currently doing a iWatch game app and its completing working. I am planing to add new feature that allow multiplayer. So the user can play against his friends locally using wifi. I have already found that iWatch can communicate to its iPhone app.

Comment: NO, iWatch can communicate with its iPhone app because they are in same App Group, in case of different apps and extensions they belong to different App Groups.

Comment: For multiplayer thing, you can create socket connection between two peers and use udp. or use http://appwarp.shephertz.com/

Answer (score 1):

I can think of only two solutions. Either you use your containing iOS app to do the communication between both players. Handling the communication between both the Apple Watch App and the iOS app will be in the delegate method `handleWatchKitExtention` in your AppDelegate. Or you can use either socket programming or heavy REST APIs requests to determine the lifetime of each player.